# how to open gnome-terminal by using php script

Tags: php

When i open gnome-terminal from my php script it errors :

```
"gdk_mir_display_open 

Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory 

Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:"
```

How to resolve it please suggest me.